# Gate instantiation in if else statement in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am designing Signed comparator that uses the unisgned comparator module.  i.e. if A and B are 4 bit vectors and

```
if A[3] ==1 and B[3]==0 then 
  Gout = 0, Eout = 0 and Lout = 1.
if A[3]==0 and B[3]==1 then 
  Gout = 1, Eout = 0 and Lout = 0;
else if both A[3] and B[3] are same then 
  the unisigned comparator module has to be instantiated.
```

How can I write this gate instantiation inside a if else statement?

```
module SCOMP(A,B,Great_in,Equal_in,Less_in,Great_out,Equal_out,Less_out);
  input[3:0] A;
  input[3:0] B;
  input Great_in,Equal_in,Less_in;
  output Great_out,Equal_out,Less_out;


  reg[3:0] X;
  reg[3:0] Y;
  reg p,q,r;
  wire x,y,z;
  initial
  begin
    X =  0000& A[2:0];
    Y =  0000& B[2:0];
  end

  COMP4 g1(X,Y,Gin,Ein,Lin,x,y,z);

  always @(*)
    begin
    if ((A[3]==0)&& (B[3]==1))
      begin
        assign p = 1;
        assign q = 0;
        assign r =0;
      end 
    else if ((A[3]== 1)&&(B[3]==0))
      begin
        assign p = 0;
        assign q = 0;
        assign r =  1;
      end 
    else 
      begin
        assign p = x;
        assign q = y;
        assign r = z;
      end
    end

  assign Great_out  = p;
  assign Equal_out = q;
  assign Less_out = r;

endmodule
```

Comment: Show us what you have created so far.

Comment: You can't instantiate gates in runtime. You must instantiate all your circuitry in the synthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog is a Hardware Description Language. Hardware either exists or it doesn't. Instantiation of anything is like soldering a chip to a PCB. Instantiating something inside an if statement would be like designing a PCB where the chips can magically appear or disappear depending on some input to the PCB.

Your "unsigned comparator module" has to exist for all time - it has to be instantiated *unconditionally*. You then need to use your `if` statements to decide whether to use the outputs from this "unsigned comparator module" or to ignore them, eg:

```
// the instance of the "unsigned comparator module"
unsigned_comparator_module UCM ( ... .gout(ucm_gout), .eout(ucm_eout), .lout(ucm_lout) ... );

always @* begin
  if (A[3] == 1 && B[3] == 0) begin
    Gout = 0; Eout = 0; Lout = 1;
  end else if (A[3] == 0 && B[3] == 1) begin
    Gout = 1; Eout = 0; Lout = 0;
  end else if (A[3] == B[3]) begin
    Gout = ucm_gout; Eout = ucm_eout; Lout = ucm_lout;
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you ..yes even I worked out in many ways to do it but ould not instantiate in if -else . I also referred to some other blogs in which I  realised the answer that you mentioned.You have explained in a very goodmanner. Thank you a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do that inside the if condition write the comparator code where u want. for eaxample

```
else if both A[3] and B[3] are same then 
  the unisigned comparator module has to be written here.
```